# Migration from jboss 4.3 to jboss EAP 6 causes high memory usage

Tags: java, memory, jboss, jvm

I have a Java application, that has been migrated from jboss 4.3 to jboss 6. To achieve this, some changes were made in the app code to make it work in jboss 6, like so:

- Include `@Local` anotation in DAO interfaces
- Include `@Stateless` anotation in DAO implementations
- Change the JNDI services
- Move all libs to the jboss modules

But we're having the problem that the app old memory (survivors) use twice the memory that survivors used to use in jboss 4.3.

Please, any help or hint about how can we set `JAVA_OPTS` params — or how to to change code, if necessary — are welcome.

Comment: Hello! I have edited your question to make use of StackOverflow's formatting markdown, and to correct grammar issues. Good luck finding an answer!